# How can I recreate lambda function via cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using `serverless` to manage IaC which uses `cloudformation` internally. There are a number of lambdas and roles defined in `serverless.yml`. It works very well until I tried to `sls remove` all resources and `sls deploy` again. After doing that, I get an error when run lambdas: `The role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda. (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: 0879c203-bec7-480b-81c6-4c7a61e2cb15`.

The error says lambda doesn't have permission however, it works if I change the lambda role to something else and change it back. It seems that lambda's role still references to the deprecated one.
I wonder what the proper way to do `remove` followed by `deploy`.

The role is:

```
{
    "Role": {
        "Path": "/",
        "RoleName": "getSiteHandlerRole",
        "RoleId": "xxxxx",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::115136697128:role/getSiteHandlerRole",
        "CreateDate": "2020-07-27T03:37:18Z",
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {
                        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
                    },
                    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Description": "",
        "MaxSessionDuration": 3600,
        "Tags": [
            {
                "Key": "STAGE",
                "Value": "user"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the role? The error suggests it has incorrect thrust policy.

Comment: I updated the role

Comment: I don't think the role has any issue. Because it works if I assign a different role to the lambda and assign it back.